# word template(.dotx) automation through c# with tables

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a word template (.dotx) that contains two tables.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
{        
    Range range = tables[3].Range;
    range.Copy();
    Range rng = tables[3].Range;
    rng.SetRange(tables[4 + i].Range.End + 2, tables[4 + i].Range.End + 2);
    rng.Paste();
    i++;

    Range rangeTestSteps = tables[4].Range;
    rangeTestSteps.Copy();
    Range rngTestSteps = tables[4].Range;
    rngTestSteps.SetRange(tables[4 + i].Range.End + 2, 
                          tables[4 + i].Range.End + 2);
    rngTestSteps.Paste();
    i++;
}
```

I am able to create table dynamically but the prob is i have to add Table of contents after every two table.Please help me.@ plutext

Answer (score 0):

You could try the approach around custom xml data binding outlined at [OpenDope.org](http://httop://www.opendope.org)

You'd need to write the C# code to process it though, since that hasn't been done yet.

There is also [Flexdoc](http://flexdoc.codeplex.com/), though I don't recall whether it will help you if you have variable number of rows in your tables.